# Increase row height in align* cases environment

Tags: amsmath, align, cases

I'm trying to use cases to present some equations with fractions, and finding that the lines are too compressed to be easily read. Is there a way to increase both the spacing between lines and the size of the typeset characters? The MWE is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
A = \begin{cases}
\frac{B-.5b}{C-.5c} & \text{sometimes} \\
\frac{D-.3d}{E-.7e} & \text{other times}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: squished text in align]

Comment: You can manually increase the height by writing `\\[2ex]` for example.

Comment: If everyone keeps adding answers, there will be nobody left to vote! `8^)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`mathtools` extends `amsmath` with `dcases`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
A = \begin{dcases}
\frac{B-.5b}{C-.5c} & \text{sometimes} \\
\frac{D-.3d}{E-.7e} & \text{other times}
\end{dcases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to add `[1ex]` of extra vertical space between the two lines. And I wouldn't use `align*` for the present case, since it features only one equation.

Comment: @Mico yes to both, I just wanted to highlight using dcases, perhaps the real example has more lines:-) (but it shouldn't use align unless there are some alignment points, I'll edit thanks

Answer (score 4):

The following shows how you can replicate `cases` using an `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  A = \begin{cases}
    \frac{B-.5b}{C-.5c} & \text{sometimes} \\
    \frac{D-.3d}{E-.7e} & \text{other times}
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
  A &= \begin{cases}
    \frac{B-.5b}{C-.5c} & \text{sometimes} \\
    \frac{D-.3d}{E-.7e} & \text{other times}
  \end{cases} \\
  A &= \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}\left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}
    \frac{B-.5b}{C-.5c} & \text{sometimes} \\
    \frac{D-.3d}{E-.7e} & \text{other times}
  \end{array}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The first `align*` replicates your output, while the second `align*` includes the original `cases` plus an `array` implementation. When using an `array`, you can adjust `\arraystretch` to stretch out the "`cases`" construction vertically (similar to other suggestions in [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764)).

Note that the default `\arraystretch` for `cases` under [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) is `1.2`, as depicted in the `\env@cases` definition (taken from [`amsmath`.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsmath.dtx)):

```
\def\env@cases{%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lbrace
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}%
}
```

Of course you could change this default `1.2` stretch factor to something larger, but my assumption is that you want only a specific instance of `cases` to be slightly aired out rather than make a global change.

---

The size of the characters can be adjusted by using `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`. However, this would require a larger `\arraystretch` than `1.5`. I'm not sure what is to be gained by this visually.

Answer (score 3):

All that I did was to invoke `\displaystyle` for each line and to insert an extra blank line. EDITED (upon Werner's reminder) to use `\dfrac` instead of `\displaystyle\frac`, when the `amsmath` package is loaded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
A = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{B-.5b}{C-.5c} & \text{sometimes} \\
\\
\dfrac{D-.3d}{E-.7e} & \text{other times}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Werner You are, of course, right.  I had forgotten that I loaded `amsmath`.

Answer (score 3):

Here are three ways:

– with the `empheq` package  (it loads `mathtools`, which loads `amsmath`, so it's pointless to load any of these);

– with the `cases*` environment (defined in `mathtools`) and `\dfrac`;

– with the `cases*` environment and `\mfrac` (medium-sized fractions, ~80 % of \displaystyle), from `nccmath`.

*Added:* There's also David Carlisle's excellent suggestion of using `dcases` (or `dcases*`), rather than my second proposition.

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}

\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}[left = {A = \empheqlbrace}]
 & \frac{B-.5b}{C-.5c} &\quad & \text{sometimes} \\
 & \frac{D-.3d}{E-.7e} & & \text{other times}
\end{alignat*}

\begin{equation*}
  A = \begin{cases*}
     \dfrac{B-.5b}{C-.5c} & sometimes \\
\dfrac{D-.3d}{E-.7e} & other times
  \end{cases*}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  A = \begin{cases*}
    \mfrac{B-.5b}{C-.5c} & sometimes \\
\mfrac{D-.3d}{E-.7e} & other times
  \end{cases*}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Note that `cases*` automatically sets the second column in `text mode`, so one doesn't have to use `text{…}`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about `cases*` and `\text{}`.
Also note that `cases*` requires `mathtools`.

Answer (score 2):

> An addition to all answers above

A useful feature is to control the **vertical distance** between the equations of the `cases`, `array`, or similar environments.
You can do that by writing `\\[your distance with units]` instead of simply `\\`. For example `\\[1.5em]`. It works also for negative spacing, e.g., `\\[-0.5em]`

In this minimal example I use `\\[1.0em]`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
        A = \begin{cases}
            \dfrac{B-.5b}{C-.5c} & \text{sometimes} \\[1.0em]
            \dfrac{D-.3d}{E-.7e} & \text{other times}
        \end{cases}
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This code is Steven B. Segletes' modified. In my opinion, it looks nicer that just an extra empty line. ;)